# JViewports with null Layouts?

Tags: java, swing, layout, awt, viewport

I got a JViewport correctly scrolling using the default layout manager (using viewport.setViewPosition), but when I call setLayout(null) this no longer works.

Any ideas?

I can give code if needs be, but it's pretty messy at the moment.

Thanks!

Edit: Thanks for the info so far. I've been using a null layout so I can absolutely position components I draw later, is there a way I can do with whilst using a layout manager?

Comment: as in "I threw away my magic wand and now I'm wondering why my spells don't work any longer" :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Scroll panes only work when the preferred size of the component added to the scroll pane is greater than the size of the scroll pane.

When you use a null layout, the preferred size is 0, so the scroll pane doesn't work. That is why you should use a layout manager. It will determine the preferred size for you.

Answer (score 5):

Don't call setLayout(null) for any reason.

Every Component should have a LayoutManager, that decide about children's size and position. So use a suitable LayoutManager or implement your own.

Answer (score -2):

If you call setLayout(null) then you need to 
Call the Component class's setbounds method for each children.
also Call repaint method.

Comment: The setBounds() method of the children has nothing to do with scrolling.